# Create directories and sub-folders according to columns in a Google spreadsheet in Python

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a spreadsheet with 5 columns and I want to create a python script that creates a directory with folders according to those 5 columns.

For example, my spreadsheet has columns A,B,C,D,E and I want to create a directory with a folder hierarchy as such A>B>C>D>E where E is a subfolder of D, C, B, and A.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Follow the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) until you can pull sheet data from Python. You can then follow the [os module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) to learn about creating directories.

Comment: I'm able to pull sheet data from python and i know to use os.makedirs() to create the directories but i'm stuck on making the folder hierarchy according to the columns in the sheet

Comment: You would just want to loop through the column names and add each name to a current_path variable while creating the previous path each time. You could also just `'/'.join(column_names)` and do a single create with the full path.

Comment: sorry i'm a beginner at python here and am having trouble with the loop over the data frame

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

folder_name1 = "A"
folder_name2 = "B"
folder_name3 = "C"
folder_name4 = "D"
folder_name5 = "D"
root = "."
path = f"{folder_name1}/{folder_name2}/{folder_name3}/{folder_name4}/{folder_name5}"
print(path)
os.makedirs(path)
```

Comment: This answers how to construct strings in python, but it fails to address the issue of pulling column data from the Google spreadsheet itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import os
# Where A,B,C,D,E is folder name.
    folder =  "A"
    folder1 = "B"
    folder2 = "C"
    folder3=  "D"
    folder4 = "E"
    root = "."
    path =f"{root}/{folder}/{folder1}/{folder2}/{folder3}/{folder4}"
    print(path)
    os.makedirs(path)
```